# The use of "its" in my sentence

Tags: word-choice

Is it wrong to use  "its" in my sentence? I was wondering if my use of "don't look" and "at the view of" is correct.

"Some people think public  breastfeeding should be forbidden. Of course if  my baby is crying for milk, I would do anything to stop its crying. I think  If you feel disgusted at the view of a nursing mother just don't look. There is nothing obscene about nursing a baby."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grammatical gender of the word "child"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/77736/grammatical-gender-of-the-word-child)

Comment: Thank you but my question is a little different. Would it be natural to use it if a woman is talking about her child?

Comment: Is  my use of "don't look" and "at the view of" correct?

Comment: Proofreading is off-topic here. You might find one of the sites listed in [Resources for Learning English](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/953/9161) more helpful.

Comment: Don't use *at the view* in this context - use ***by** the **sight** [of something unusual/ disturbing]*.

Comment: Is it correct in other contexts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Just don't look" is perfectly fine.

Rather than "at the view of a nursing mother" you should use "at the **sight** of a nursing mother." You could use the particle "seeing a nursing mother" instead of "at the sight of" if you wanted to.

A mother talking about her own child would probably use "his/her/their" rather than "its"—but I would not think twice if she did use "its."

Comment: Would it be rude to use "its" or "it" hen talking about someone else's child?

Comment: In the case of an anonymous baby. no. For a friend's baby whose gender you know, yes.